# Issues with IF EXIST ELSE being ignored in DOS 6.22 Batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos

I'm currently working on an old legacy MS-DOS 6.22 system that now requires different batch files to be called depending on if a file exists on C:.
I placed the following in AUTOEXEC.BAT:

```
IF EXIST C:\IMGOK.TXT (BOOT.BAT) ELSE (LOADIMG.BAT)
```

Something must be off because it seems to be ignoring this statement and calling neither of the .BAT files I specified.  This is regardless of if IMGOK.TXT exists.  IMGOK.TXT is an empty text file created via
    COPY NUL>IMGOK.TXT
I have tried both with and without the parenthesis around the statements.

Am I missing something with how to use this IF EXIST ELSE statement?
Thank you in advance for the help.

EDIT: Got it, can't use ELSE in DOS batch files.  Had to use IF EXISTS and IF NOT EXISTS for my different calls.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `call` instead of loading the `.bat` files directly?

Comment: MS-DOS doesn't support ELSE or grouping commands with parentheses.

Comment: I just gave that a shot and no luck: IF EXIST C:\IMGOK.TXT CALL BOOT.BAT ELSE CALL LOADIMG.BAT

Comment: The ELSE was it.  Didn't realize DOS batch files can't use ELSE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MS-DOS doesn't support the ELSE keyword. It also doesn't support using parentheses to group commands. This means if the file `C:\IMGOK.TXT` exists then the command `(BOOT.BAT` is executed with arguments `ELSE (LOADIMG.BAT)`. Since you probably don't have a file named `(BOOT.BAT` this will cause an error if `C:\IMGOK.TXT` exists and do nothing if it doesn't.

A simple way to solve your problem is to use two IF statements:

```
 IF EXIST C:\IMGOK.TXT BOOT.BAT
 IF NOT EXIST C:\IMGOK.TXT LOADIMG.BAT
```

Since running `BOOT.BAT` will end further processing of commands in `AUTOEXEC.BAT` you can also do:

```
 IF EXIST C:\IMGOK.TXT BOOT.BAT
 LOADIMG.BAT
```